# Exception handling in Parallel.Invoke inside a Task

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I have the following code

```
var exceptions = new ConcurrentQueue<Exception>();
Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    try
    {
        Parallel.Invoke(
            async () => await _aViewModel.LoadData(_someId),
            async () => await _bViewModel.LoadData(_someId)
        );
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        exceptions.Enqueue(ex);
    }
}).ContinueWith((continuation) =>
    {
        if (exceptions.Count > 0) throw new AggregateException(exceptions);
    });
```

I am using Task.StartNew here because the LoadData method use the Dispatcher.StartAsync method to invoke on the main UI thread internally.

The problem I have is that if I force `_aViewModel.LoadData` to throw an exception it is not caught in the Catch(Exception) clause (nor if I catch AggregateException). I don't understand why!?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Parallel.Invoke` is not `async`-aware. So your `async` lambdas are being converted to `async void` methods, which have extremely awkward error semantics (they are not allowed to leave the `async void` method; instead, they are captured and re-raised directly on the `SynchronizationContext` that was active at the time the `async void` method started - in this case, the thread pool).

I'm not sure why you have the `Parallel.Invoke` in the first place. Since your method is already `async`, you could just do something like this:

```
Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
{
    try
    {
        Task.WaitAll(
            _aViewModel.LoadData(_someId),
            _bViewModel.LoadData(_someId)
        );
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        exceptions.Enqueue(ex);
    }
})...
```

P.S. If you have the time, rethink the structure of this whole part of the code. `Dispatcher.StartAsync` is a code smell. The UI should be (asynchronously) requesting data; the data retrieval objects should not have to know about the UI.

Comment: The reason I am currently using Dispatcher.StartAsync is the LoadData methods are getting data from web services, and loading into ObservableCollections which are complaining unless invoked back across to the main thread.

Comment: Treat all your data-bound objects / ViewModels (e.g., `ObservableCollections`) as your "logical UI". Then your "logical UI" should be requesting the data from (asynchronous) methods that *return* it, rather than *set it as a side effect*. That change in perspective will help clean up the code.

Comment: I can't quite get the syntax for returning an IEnumerable<x> from the LoadData method. They return Task<IEnumerable<x>> but using `var data = _aViewModel.LoadData(_someId)` doesn't compile.

Comment: @ColinDesmond: You use `await` to unwrap the `Task`. So, if `LoadDataAsync` returns `Task<IEnumerable<x>>`, then if you `await` that task, you'll end up with an `IEnumerable<x>`. Like this: `IEnumerable<x> data = _aViewModel.LoadDataAsync(_someId);`. You may find my [`async` intro helpful](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).

Answer (score 3):

`Parallel.Invoke` takes an array of `Action` delegates. It has no means of knowing that your delegates are actually `async` methods, and therefore it returns before your tasks have completed.

For an in-depth explanation of this behaviour, watch [Lucian Wischik's Channel 9 video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Three-Essential-Tips-for-Async/Tip-1-Async-void-is-for-top-level-event-handlers-only) on the subject.

Try changing your code to use the [Task.WhenAll method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.

```
var aTask = _aViewModel.LoadData(_someId);
var bTask = _bViewModel.LoadData(_someId);
await Task.WhenAll(aTask, bTask);
```